# CSS doesn't work when I display div from php code

Tags: php, html, css

I want to make a navigation menu where I display the page and at the bottom I have the numbers of the next pages that I can enter.
 My problem is that when I enter the code statically:

```
    <div id="page2" class="page"><?php petla(2); ?></div>
    <div id="page3" class="page"><?php petla(3); ?></div>
    <div id="page1" class="page default"><?php petla(1); ?></div>
```

and

```
    <div class="nawigacja">
      <nav>
          <a href="#page1">Page 1</a>
          <a href="#page2">Page 2</a>
          <a href="#page3">Page 3</a>
     </nav>
   </div>
```

and adds
 `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dodatek.css">`
inside

```
    .page {
            display: none;
          }
    .default {
           display: block;
             }
    :target {
          display: block;
            }
    :target ~ .default {
          display: none;
           }
```

Then code works, but I need this do in loop and I wrote something like that but php can't see css and can't connect it in any way still displaying all pages  instead of one

```
<?php
       echo '<div id="page2" class="page">'.petla(2).';</div>';
       echo '<div id="page1" class="page default">'.petla(1).';</div>';
?>
```

Summarizing:
This works :

```
      <div id="page2" class="page"><?php petla(2); ?></div>
     <div id="page3" class="page"><?php petla(3); ?></div>
     <div id="page1" class="page default"><?php petla(1); ?></div>
```

and

this doesn't work (should display only page1,shows everything):

```
    echo '<div id="page2" class="page">'.petla(2).';</div>';
    echo '<div id="page1" class="page default">'.petla(1).';</div>';
```

Function petla is not important. It just needs to work on the string.

Comment: `';</div>';` remove `;` or should be `'</div>';`

Comment: I did it, unchanged, everything is still displayed.

Comment: use JavaScript, to accomplish  what you need

Comment: You don't show what your desired output is. PHP has no connection with CSS; outputting HTML via PHP, vs. outputting it statically, results in no difference in relation to client-side tech like CSS, JavaScript etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your 2 methods : 
`<div id="page2" class="page"><?php petla(2); ?></div>`
and 
`echo '<div id="page2" class="page">'.petla(2).';</div>';`

Did you try them on the same html page ? If so, there is no reason that HTML generated by PHP could not be affected by CSS ; I can't reproduce your issue :

```
    <html>
<style>
    .page {
        display: none;
    }
    .default {
        display: block;
    }
    :target {
        display: block;
    }
    :target ~ .default {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<body>
<?php
function petla($number)
{
    return $number;
}
?>
<!--php in HTML method-->
<div id="page2a" class="page"><?= petla(2); ?></div>
<div id="page1a" class="page default"><?= petla(1); ?></div>

<!--HTML in php method-->
<?php
echo '<div id="page2b" class="page">' . petla(2) . '</div>';
echo '<div id="page1b" class="page default">' . petla(1) . '</div>';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Result : [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjxoD.png)

To debug it, try to modify background color properties instead of display none.
May be you are not seeing items because of "Note (2)"

Notes :

- You have an extra semicolon here `petla(2).';</div>`
- If you would like to display what is returning petla function you should use `<?= petla(x); ?>` instead of `<?php petla(x); ?>`

Here is some ways to perform loop for your use case

```
<?php
for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++){
    echo '<div id="page'.$x.'" class="page">' . petla($x) . '</div>';
}
?>

<?php for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++): ?>
    <div id="page<?= $x ?>" class="page"><?= petla($x); ?></div>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

You can also check ob_start, ob_get_clean for more complexe objects.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to implement the `echo`. This is another way.

```
<?php
echo '<div id="page2" class="page">', petla(2), '</div>';
echo '<div id="page1" class="page default">', petla(1), '</div>';
?>
```

Test it with text instead of the function:

```
'petla(2)'
```

Comment: for index.php(default) showing test1 (good),  for page1 showing test1(good), for page2 showing test1,test2(bad, need hidden test1),  for page3 showing test1,test3(bad, need hidden test1).